# Birational Transform of a Divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a birational morphism between normal varieties. Let $V\subset X$ be a prime divisor of $X$, i.e. irreducible closed subvariety of codimension 1.

Choosing an open subset $U$ of $X$ for which $f$ is regular on such that $V\cap U \neq \emptyset$, we define the **birational transform** of $V$ to the closure of $f(U\cap V)$ in $Y$, and we denote it as $\tilde{V}$. My question is, is $\tilde{V}$ still of codimension 1 in $Y$?

We know that $\dim X = \dim Y$ since they are birational to one another. Suppose $f$ maps $U$ isomorphically to an open subset $U’ \subset Y$. Then $1=\operatorname{codim}(U\cap V , U) = \operatorname{codim}(f(U\cap V), U’)$ (please correct me if I’m wrong.)

Can we further assert that $\operatorname{codim}(\tilde{V},Y) =1$? This appears to be the case in many of the resources I have encountered online but I can’t seem to see why. This question may be obvious to many but I just wish to untangle some technical baggages.. any help given would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something subtle, but from my POV this comes down to $\dim X = \dim Y = n$, so $\operatorname{codim}(V, X) = $ means that $\dim V = n-1$. Thus $\operatorname{codim}(\overline V, Y) = 1$. The only way I can see this being harder is if you're working with definition of codimension other than "the difference between the dimension of the subvariety and the dimension of the ambient variety."

Comment: @TabesBridges Hi, I guess the main question for me is how do I get the implication $\operatorname{codim}(V,X) \Rightarrow \operatorname{codim}(\overline{V},Y)$. In this situation, I have the image of $V$ (locally) under $f$ is a closed subset $f(U\cap Y)$ of some open subset $U’$ of $Y$. How do I know upon the codim is preserved under taking closure of $f(U\cap Y)$ in $Y$?

Comment: I guess my question would be: is it not clear to you that the dimension of a variety cannot increase upon taking the closure?

Comment: @TabesBridges Yeap that is the part that is not clear to me apriori at all... unless I am missing something very obvious here. I gave the question some thought and this is what I have: Write $f(U\cap V) = \tilde{V} \cap U’$.Then by lemma 5.11.2 here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02I0 we have $\operatorname{codim}(\tilde{V},Y) = \operatorname{codim}(f(U\cap V), U’) = 1$, as written above. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: I just wrote several comments and then deleted because I realized your statement is false: consider the exceptional divisor $E$ of the blowup $f: \mathbb F_1 \to \mathbb P^2$ of the plane at a point $p$. This is a birational morphism between smooth varieties with $\operatorname{codim}(E,\mathbb F_1) = 1$ but $\operatorname{codim}(p,\mathbb P^2) = 2$. You need to add a hypothesis that ensures $V \not\subset\operatorname{Exc}(f) \subset X$ ; otherwise I believe that $V$ is necessarily contracted by the hypothesis of $Y$ normal.

Comment: I'm confusing myself trying to make further assertions, but I am concerned by the fact that your hypothesis is that $f$ is a birational *morphism*, but you pass to an open subset on which $f$ is regular. But $f$ is already regular everywhere; did you mean the later assumption that $f|_U$ is an isomorphism? Alternatively, I think that first step extends the result to birational maps instead of just birational morphisms.

Comment: @TabesBridges I wrote $f$ is a birational morphism because this was the context given in the book I am reading ... but just having $f$ to be a birational map is fine ok it seems. And yes i am referring to the later assumption that $f|_U$ is an isomorphism so I am passing down to the isomorphic open sets of $X$ and $Y$.